# Creating Oracle APEX Dynamic Menu via oracle table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am trying to add dynamic menu in Oracle APEX through oracle table using sql query. It will have n levels of menu (Menu will have sub-menu, sub menu will have further menu under it), should not be restricted to any number of nodes.

I have already created the dynamic navigation menu bar with oracle table and hierarchical query but the sequence is not coming correct. Could you please help me with below to achieve this -

1. Table structure
2. Sample table data
3. SQL Query

I am attaching a sample snapshot to show what I am trying to achieve.

[Nested Menu Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndZi9.jpg)

Please Note - I am not looking for dynamic menu which is fully Javascript driven.

Comment: Actually, should be vice versa: it is YOU who should provide table structure, sample data and SQL query you wrote so far (but it doesn't return desired result) so that *community* might try to assist.

Comment: CREATE TABLE MENU
(
    ROOT_NODE       NUMBER,
    LEAF_NODE       NUMBER,
    MENU_NAME       VARCHAR2(4000),
    PAGE_NO         NUMBER
)


SELECT
LEVEL,
MENU_NAME LABEL,
ROOT_NODE, LEAF_NODE
'f?p=&APP_ID.:1:' || :APP_SESSION || ':::::' TARGET,
'NO' IS_CURRENT
FROM MENU
START WITH ROOT_NODE IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR LEAF_NODE = ROOT_NODE;
ORDER SIBLINGS BY MENU_NAME;